# Bokeh - how to change fill_color of varea_stack using JS callback

Tags: callback, jupyter, bokeh

I wanted to plot a stack of lines like matplotlib stackplot in a jupyter notebook. Then, I wanted to gray out all the data but one, using a select widget to select the data I wanted to retained. For that, a callback is required.

I am having trouble updating the fill_color of the VArea glyph renderers returned by Bokeh varea_stack.

MWE

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import column, 
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.colors import Color, RGB
output_notebook()

import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,20)
y1 = 10*np.ones_like(x)
y2 = x

indeces = [1,2]

p = figure()

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2))

colors = [RGB(200,50,50), RGB(100,100,250)]

stack = p.varea_stack(["y"+str(i) for i in indeces], x='x', source=source, fill_color=colors)
select = Select(title="Line", value="All", options=["All"]+[str(i) for i in indeces])

args = dict(
    colors = colors,
    stack = stack
)

callback = CustomJS(args=args, code="""
    var k = cb_obj.value
    var colors = colors;
    
    for (var i=0; i<colors.length; i++){
        if (k != "All"){
            if (k != i+1){
            stack[i].fill_color = "rgb(0,0,0)"
            }
            else{
                stack[i].fill_color = colors[i];
            }
        }
        else{
            stack[i].fill_color = colors[i];
        }
    }
""")

select.js_on_change("value", callback)
c = column(select, p)
show(c)
```

Output

[image]

Now, I would like to click on "1" in the Select Widget and grey out the data corresponding to y2 (i.e. the blue triangle).

Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I had to replace

`stack[i].fill_color` by `stack[i].glyph.fill_color` in the js callback.